# making phpmailer not echoing out empty inputs with if statment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form with inputs, if the customer does not know something he leaves the field empty and submits the form it then sends an email they can get pretty long depending on the form. So IM trying to make it so when a input is empty it does not echo it out in the phpmailer. However, I'm not sure how to do it really, SO this is what I have come up with. What am I doing wrong?

```html
 // defines how message looks in email
$mail->Body="
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<span style='color:red;'>This customer needs a repair quote. Lets not keep him waiting!</span>
<div style='width:750px;text-align:center;'>


<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Personal Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Full Name: </span>$name<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Phone Number:</span> $phone<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Email:</span> $email<br></span>
</div>
<br>
<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Vehicle Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle make:</span> $make<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle Model:</span> $model<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Year:</span> $year<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vin:</span> $vin<br></span>






if (empty($_POST[$message])) {
// Evaluates post if empty moves on. If somone puts text in in echos it out
// do nothing or move to next line of code
echo '';
} else {
    echo '<br><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>message:</span>$message<br></span>';
   




</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html> 


";
```

Comment: You can't have an opening PHP tag, or PHP code like that inside a string.

Comment: `font-size:px` will do nothing at all! Echoing anything from $_POST directly is profoundly unsafe. You're only being rescued by the fact that email clients are mostly not vulnerable to XSS, but it would be a *very* good idea to do some input filtering and output escaping anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php 
$tbody = "
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<span style='color:red;'>This customer needs a repair quote. Lets not keep him waiting!</span>
<div style='width:750px;text-align:center;'>


<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Personal Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>";
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {
$tbody .= "
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Full Name: </span>$name<br></span>
<br>
";
}

if (!empty($_POST["phone"])) {
$tbody .= "
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Phone Number:</span> $phone<br></span>
<br>";
}


if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
$tbody .=  "
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Email:</span> $email<br></span>
";
}

$tbody .= "</div>
<br>
<div style='float:;'>
<span style='font-size:px;'><b>Vehicle Info</b><br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'>---------------<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle make:</span> $make<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vehicle Model:</span> $model<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Year:</span> $year<br></span>
<br>
<span style='font-size:px;'><span style='font-size:px;color:red;'>Vin:</span> $vin<br></span>

</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html> 


";
$mail->Body = $tbody;
?>
```

- I've only added the check to three parameters but you can do it as much as you want.
- `.=` Sign means `add the next string to the previous string`

Comment: kinda works but its backwards shows text if empty and shows nothing if filled.
https://ibb.co/zFfCn0M

Answer (score 0):

use `var_dump` (just for debugging) to check what is the value in `$message`. then replace `empty` check with the another predicate, I.E. `!= "null"` if $message is the string `null`.